# Restore large MySQL dump thorugh EasyPHP

Tags: mysql, restore, dump

I am trying to upload large files on easyphp but as there is limitation on this software and large databases cannot be uploaded. Is there some other software that allows to import large databases? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySql Workbench for managing your remote database

here is the link for downloading MySql Workbench

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

I would use `BigDump` for this.

`BigDump` - http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/ - The script imports only a small part of the huge dump and restarts itself. The next session starts where the last was stopped.